# merge sort not working when copying the result of merge operation directly to auxiliary array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, mergesort

Here is the code which i am using for merge sort

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int merge(int *arr,int *b,int low,int mid,int high)
{
    int i,j,k;
    i = low;
    j = mid+1;

//  printf("low: %d mid: %d high: %d\n",low,mid,high);
    for(k=low;k<=high;k++)
    {
        b[k] = arr[k];
    }
    k = low;
    while((i <= mid) && (j <= high))
    {
        if(b[i] <= b[j])
        {
            arr[k++] = b[i++];
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k++] = b[j++];
        }
    }
    while(i<=mid)
        arr[k++] = b[i++];
    while(j<=high)
        arr[k++] = b[j++];
}

int merge_sort(int *arr,int *b,int low,int high)
{
    int mid;
    if(low<high)
    {
        mid = (low)+(high - low)/2;
        merge_sort(arr,b,low,mid);
        merge_sort(arr,b,mid+1,high);
        merge(arr,b,low,mid,high);
    }
    return 0;
}

int temp_merge(int *arr,int *b,int low,int mid,int high)
{
    int i,j,k;
    i = low;
    j = mid+1;
    k = low;

    while((i <= mid) && (j <= high))
    {
        if(arr[i] <= arr[j])
        {
            b[k++] = arr[i++];
        }
        else
        {
            b[k++] = arr[j++];
        }
    }
    while(i<=mid)
        b[k++] = arr[i++];
    while(j<=high)
        b[k++] = arr[j++];
}

int temp_merge_sort(int *arr,int *b,int low,int high)
{
    int mid;
    if(low<high)
    {
        mid = (low)+(high - low)/2;
        temp_merge_sort(arr,b,low,mid);
        temp_merge_sort(arr,b,mid+1,high);
        temp_merge(arr,b,low,mid,high);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int a[100],b[100],i;
    a[0] = 34;
    a[1] = 3;
    a[2] = 14;
    a[3] = 4;
    a[4] = 25;
    a[5] = 67;
    a[6] = 11;
    a[7] = 8;
    a[8] = 12;
    a[9] = 1;
    printf("contents of array a\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    printf("\n");
    merge_sort(a,b,0,9);
    printf("after using merge_sort function\n");
    printf("contents of auxillary array b\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("%d ",b[i]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("contents of array a\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    printf("\n");
    a[0] = 34;
    a[1] = 3;
    a[2] = 14;
    a[3] = 4;
    a[4] = 25;
    a[5] = 67;
    a[6] = 11;
    a[7] = 8;
    a[8] = 12;
    a[9] = 1;
    printf("contents of array a after reassigning values\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    printf("\n");
    temp_merge_sort(a,b,0,9);
    printf("after using temp_merge_sort function\n");
    printf("contents of auxillary array b\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("%d ",b[i]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("contents of array a\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

I got the following output for this code

```
contents of array a
34 3 14 4 25 67 11 8 12 1 
after using merge_sort function
contents of auxillary array b
3 4 14 25 34 1 8 11 12 67 
contents of array a
1 3 4 8 11 12 14 25 34 67 
contents of array a after reassigning values
34 3 14 4 25 67 11 8 12 1 
after using temp_merge_sort function
contents of auxillary array b
34 3 14 4 25 67 11 8 12 1 
contents of array a
34 3 14 4 25 67 11 8 12 1
```

Initially I filled array with some numbers. Then I called the function merge_sort. This function recursively calls itself until low less than high. Then merge operation is performed on sub arrays. That is implemented in the function merge in which first elements of original array are copied to auxiliary array and then merge operation is performed. This is working fine and the resulting sorted numbers will be stored in original array.

After that I am refilling the original array with unsorted values and calling the function temp_merge_sort function. This is similar to merge_sort function except that in this merge operation is performed by temp_merge function. In this function instead of copying original array values from low to high to auxiliary array I directly performed merge operation on contents of original array and copied the result to auxiliary array. This is not working fine and contents of auxiliary array remain same as original array unsorted. I don't understand where I made mistake. Could anyone please help out ???

-Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At each pass, you are putting the "sorted" elements in `b`; but since your code is assuming that the elements in `arr` are becoming more and more sorted, the operation you are performing isn't doing anything useful (because you would need to copy the sorted elements from `b` back into `arr`, or rely on the increasingly sorted `b` as the source of the data which is further sorted).

There is no "one line" solution I can think of given your current code - but that is in essence the problem you have.